# Laravel - List of all default validation error messages

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use the Laravel Validator class for a PHP project that is not made in laravel. Essentially I'm doing something similar to [Illuminate Validator in stand-alone non-Laravel application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573889/illuminate-validator-in-stand-alone-non-laravel-application)

Here's my code:

```
        $filesystem = new \Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem();
        $fileLoader = new \Illuminate\Translation\FileLoader($filesystem, '');
        $translator = new \Illuminate\Translation\Translator($fileLoader, 'en_US');

        $messages = [
            'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
            'string' => 'The :attribute field must be a string.',
        ];


        $factory = new \Illuminate\Validation\Factory($translator);
        $rules = [
            'title' => 'required'
        ];


        $validator = $factory->make($this->request->post(), $rules, $messages);

        $validator = new \Illuminate\Validation\Validator($translator, $this->request->post(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $errors = $validator->errors();
            foreach ($errors->all() as $message) {
                var_dump($message);
            }
        }die;
```

My problem here is that I need to create all the error validation messages myself. I was wondering if there is a way use the default Laravel error messages. I'm even considering setting all those default error messages as one complete array in a seperate file, if I could get those. Any ideas where I can find all the default validation error messages for Laravel?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the list of all default error messages

> https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/lang/en/validation.php

```
[
'accepted'             => 'The :attribute must be accepted.',
'active_url'           => 'The :attribute is not a valid URL.',
'after'                => 'The :attribute must be a date after :date.',
'after_or_equal'       => 'The :attribute must be a date after or equal to :date.',
'alpha'                => 'The :attribute may only contain letters.',
'alpha_dash'           => 'The :attribute may only contain letters, numbers, dashes and underscores.',
'alpha_num'            => 'The :attribute may only contain letters and numbers.',
'array'                => 'The :attribute must be an array.',
'before'               => 'The :attribute must be a date before :date.',
'before_or_equal'      => 'The :attribute must be a date before or equal to :date.',
'between'              => [
    'numeric' => 'The :attribute must be between :min and :max.',
    'file'    => 'The :attribute must be between :min and :max kilobytes.',
    'string'  => 'The :attribute must be between :min and :max characters.',
    'array'   => 'The :attribute must have between :min and :max items.',
],
'boolean'              => 'The :attribute field must be true or false.',
'confirmed'            => 'The :attribute confirmation does not match.',
'date'                 => 'The :attribute is not a valid date.',
'date_format'          => 'The :attribute does not match the format :format.',
'different'            => 'The :attribute and :other must be different.',
'digits'               => 'The :attribute must be :digits digits.',
'digits_between'       => 'The :attribute must be between :min and :max digits.',
'dimensions'           => 'The :attribute has invalid image dimensions.',
'distinct'             => 'The :attribute field has a duplicate value.',
'email'                => 'The :attribute must be a valid email address.',
'exists'               => 'The selected :attribute is invalid.',
'file'                 => 'The :attribute must be a file.',
'filled'               => 'The :attribute field must have a value.',
'gt'                   => [
    'numeric' => 'The :attribute must be greater than :value.',
    'file'    => 'The :attribute must be greater than :value kilobytes.',
    'string'  => 'The :attribute must be greater than :value characters.',
    'array'   => 'The :attribute must have more than :value items.',
],
'gte'                  => [
    'numeric' => 'The :attribute must be greater than or equal :value.',
    'file'    => 'The :attribute must be greater than or equal :value kilobytes.',
    'string'  => 'The :attribute must be greater than or equal :value characters.',
    'array'   => 'The :attribute must have :value items or more.',
],
'image'                => 'The :attribute must be an image.',
'in'                   => 'The selected :attribute is invalid.',
'in_array'             => 'The :attribute field does not exist in :other.',
'integer'              => 'The :attribute must be an integer.',
'ip'                   => 'The :attribute must be a valid IP address.',
'ipv4'                 => 'The :attribute must be a valid IPv4 address.',
'ipv6'                 => 'The :attribute must be a valid IPv6 address.',
'json'                 => 'The :attribute must be a valid JSON string.',
'lt'                   => [
    'numeric' => 'The :attribute must be less than :value.',
    'file'    => 'The :attribute must be less than :value kilobytes.',
    'string'  => 'The :attribute must be less than :value characters.',
    'array'   => 'The :attribute must have less than :value items.',
],
'lte'                  => [
    'numeric' => 'The :attribute must be less than or equal :value.',
    'file'    => 'The :attribute must be less than or equal :value kilobytes.',
    'string'  => 'The :attribute must be less than or equal :value characters.',
    'array'   => 'The :attribute must not have more than :value items.',
],
'max'                  => [
    'numeric' => 'The :attribute may not be greater than :max.',
    'file'    => 'The :attribute may not be greater than :max kilobytes.',
    'string'  => 'The :attribute may not be greater than :max characters.',
    'array'   => 'The :attribute may not have more than :max items.',
],
'mimes'                => 'The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.',
'mimetypes'            => 'The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.',
'min'                  => [
    'numeric' => 'The :attribute must be at least :min.',
    'file'    => 'The :attribute must be at least :min kilobytes.',
    'string'  => 'The :attribute must be at least :min characters.',
    'array'   => 'The :attribute must have at least :min items.',
],
'not_in'               => 'The selected :attribute is invalid.',
'not_regex'            => 'The :attribute format is invalid.',
'numeric'              => 'The :attribute must be a number.',
'present'              => 'The :attribute field must be present.',
'regex'                => 'The :attribute format is invalid.',
'required'             => 'The :attribute field is required.',
'required_if'          => 'The :attribute field is required when :other is :value.',
'required_unless'      => 'The :attribute field is required unless :other is in :values.',
'required_with'        => 'The :attribute field is required when :values is present.',
'required_with_all'    => 'The :attribute field is required when :values is present.',
'required_without'     => 'The :attribute field is required when :values is not present.',
'required_without_all' => 'The :attribute field is required when none of :values are present.',
'same'                 => 'The :attribute and :other must match.',
'size'                 => [
    'numeric' => 'The :attribute must be :size.',
    'file'    => 'The :attribute must be :size kilobytes.',
    'string'  => 'The :attribute must be :size characters.',
    'array'   => 'The :attribute must contain :size items.',
],
'string'               => 'The :attribute must be a string.',
'timezone'             => 'The :attribute must be a valid zone.',
'unique'               => 'The :attribute has already been taken.',
'uploaded'             => 'The :attribute failed to upload.',
'url'                  => 'The :attribute format is invalid.'
]
```

Comment: Link only answer is discouraged: You should add a sample or copy of the information you're referring to just in case the link gets broken in the future.